# openlayer 3.5 get feature id from point

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

I m still learning openlayers and i have a problem. I need for my script the id of a point if this is clicked. With this id(that function as a variable) i want to do some coding.

With help of some examples i manage to get a table on my website.I do this with the following code(javascript):

```
map.on('singleclick', function(evt) {
    document.getElementById('nodelist').innerHTML = "Loading... please wait...";
    var view = map.getView();
    var viewResolution = view.getResolution();
    var source = untiled.get('visible') ? untiled.getSource() : tiled.getSource();
    var url = source.getGetFeatureInfoUrl(
      evt.coordinate, viewResolution, view.getProjection(),
      {'INFO_FORMAT': 'text/html', 'FEATURE_COUNT': 50});
    if (url) {
      document.getElementById('nodelist').innerHTML = '<iframe seamless src="' + url + '"></iframe>';
    }
  });
```

But what i want is not to display the table and get the id of the point out of the table.

Can somebody give me some tips?

Comment: It depends. Show some more code, specially how do add them to the source.

Comment: The poster is working with a WMS layer, so the features are not available client side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want access to feature ids, you cannot use the 'text/html' format in your GetFeatureInfo request. Instead, you will have to use a 'application/vnd.ogc.gml' or 'application/json' format. This will only work if the server allows CORS requests, or if the server is on the same origin as your application. Then, instead of using the url from `source.getGetFeatureInfoUrl()` in an IFRAME, you will have to use it in an AJAX request. Parse the response using `ol.format.WMSGetFeatureInfo` or `ol.format.GeoJSON`, and for the parsed features you can then get the id by simply using `ol.Feature#getId()`.